# Add Shadow Column to Insert Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Situation: 
I developed a Database that heavily depends on a lot of triggers to ensure data consistency (To fulfill the CFR 21 Part 11).
There are 2 tables to store users: `Login & User` (in favor of the Sql servers User management). Users contains static login data for External authentication and X1 are containing login data for our system (Fake User). A person have to login into our application using one of the `Login` data (Real User). When the system must communicate with an external system (Active Directory or FileSystem or Database) the corresponding `User`(Fake User) will be impersonated.

For Clarification will use X1(Real User) for Login and X2(Fake User) for User.

When the X2 is connected to the database the trigger does not know who the X1 is.

Problem:
The Trigger will log each action done by the X2 and write it the Log. As the server only knows that X2 is connected to the database it is not aware of the Real user X1.

The Customer whats to also see who the RealUser X1 was. As this information is lost when connected to the Database i have this Problem now.

Solution Attempts:

1. Create a StoredProcedure that takes the RealUser x1 as an Argument. This is not possible as old software relies on the current to Insert and Update the Table.
2. Add Additional Data the Insert/Update statement (is that possible i did not found anything related to that). The data will only used by the Trigger and should no be written to the Table.
3. Add the info about the current X1 user to the Connection or to a general Connection based store (does something like this exist in SqlServer?)
4. Use the ApplicationName property for "faking" the Username. But this makes me feel like wearing a monocle. There must be a better way

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187768) to associate extra data with the session that can be accessed in the trigger (like, say, the original user identity):

```
DECLARE @UID VARBINARY(128) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), N'User1')
SET CONTEXT_INFO @UID

-- Later, at the Hall of Justice
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(64), CONTEXT_INFO())
```

Of course, you could use a different way of identifying the user than a Unicode string, as long as it eventually fits in a `VARBINARY(128)`.

For this to work you must consistently set the information before executing any command (the context info will be reset when the connection is closed). There are also security concerns -- `SET CONTEXT_INFO` is not a privileged statement and could be executed by anyone, so you must be sure you control all code in the database lest the audit information is falsified.